# Can you measure mass using an accelerometer?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, vibrations

Is it possible to use an accelerometer and a microcontroller to measure mass of an object up to 500g. These two electronics would be attached and be portable.

Comment: Not as stated. F=ma so you must apply a known force/impulse as well as know the frictional forces present. By the way, gravity is not a known force. It's a known acceleration. The force applied by gravity changes with the object's mass which is why the acceleration stays the same for small objects.

Comment: It is possible to measure mass by measuring the frequency of that mass while attached to an oscillating spring.  While the spring is not an accelerometer, that method of measuring mass is in a sense analogous to your idea.

Comment: You mention 500g. The maximum mass shouldn't be significant to the act of establishing the mass. This would really only become significant if the body was "very big" (planet-sized) and "very close".